# Sub-string for both Locate and Instr in Mysql and Oracle

Tags: mysql, regex, oracle

I have this 2 query which i am running one for Mysql 5.7  and One for Oracle .
Is this possible to have one query that will work for both Mysql and Oracle .

```
SUBSTR(fg.PATH, 2, INSTR(fg.PATH, '/', 1, 2) - 2) - in oracle
SUBSTR(fg.PATH, 2, locate( '/',fg.PATH, 2) - 2) - in mysql
```

I have tried the regex but no luck .
Any kind of expression but which should work for both .

Here is the main query that i need to replace

```
select *
from tab1 fg
         inner join CENV ce on ce.CID=SUBSTR(fg.PATH, 2, INSTR(fg.PATH, '/', 1, 2) - 2)
```

My Application will not allow to write function and procedure or any trigger ...

Comment: you could create a [mysql function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) `INSTR` with the same oracle arguments that calls `locate.`

Comment: Yea i though of the same but function and procedure is not allowed in our application ..So anything around query and expression ?

Comment: because mysql INSTR is two args, remove the first char of path. and concat it back outside the substr.

Comment: One example would be great ...And can you please post answer also ...

Comment: Could you please give an example of what the value of  `fg.PATH` looks like?

Comment: @Nick yes here it is `/euwuue-65f7-1bd0-997e-ae9a00005646/0a348753-65f7-1a20-997e-refefdf/`

Comment: @Anupam I've updated my answer with demos using that sample value

Comment: It is folly to try to make a single SQL that works across multiple vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression will give you the same result as your original Oracle expression on both Oracle and MySQL 5.7:

```
SUBSTR(fg.path, 2, INSTR(fg.path, '/') + INSTR(SUBSTR(fg.path, 1 + INSTR(fg.path, '/')), '/') - 2)
```

[Demo on MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91a9d471bb5508d24c427fee9dfbb9e0)
[Demo on Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91a9d471bb5508d24c427fee9dfbb9e0)